# count a grouped by and cased mysql

Tags: mysql

Im trying to get the age of each person by computing on their birthday. Now I need to group them which I already achieved. Now what I want is to count how many in group 20 and below and so forth and so on.

Here's my query

```
select case when datediff(now(), birthday) / 365.25 > 50 then '51 & over' when datediff(now(), birthday) / 365.25 > 30 then '31 - 50' when datediff(now(), birthday) / 365.25 > 19 then '20 - 30' else 'under 20' end as age_group from members
```

The result is

[image]

Where I tried to group it by the query below

```
select case when datediff(now(), birthday) / 365.25 > 50 then '51 & over' when datediff(now(), birthday) / 365.25 > 30 then '31 - 50' when datediff(now(), birthday) / 365.25 > 19 then '20 - 30' else 'under 20' end as age_group from members group by age_group
```

Result will be
[image]

But what I need is somethinglike this
[image]

**NOte: Photo edited.

How do I achieved that I need to place the count result in a chart.

Comment: Show us some sample data and your desired result will be more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the query similar to this:

```
Select age_group, count(*)
From (
  // your original query here
) t
Group by age_group
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a count(*) to your last query:

```
   select case when datediff(now(), birthday) / 365.25 > 50 then '51 & over' when datediff(now(), birthday) / 365.25 > 30 then '31 - 50' when datediff(now(), birthday) / 365.25 > 19 then '20 - 30' else 'under 20' end as age_group, count(*) from members group by age_group
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
concat(
    datediff(now(), birthday)/365.25 div 20 * 20 + 1,
    '-',
    (datediff(now(), birthday)/365.25 div 20 + 1) * 20) AS age,
count(*)
FROM members
GROUP BY datediff(now(), birthday)/365.25 DIV 20
```

This query will give the result in the following format

```
+-------+----------+
| age   | count(*) |
+-------+----------+
| 1-20  |        2 |
| 21-40 |        1 |
| 41-60 |        1 |
+-------+----------+
```

Based on the following table definition and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE `stack` (
`id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`birthdate` date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

insert into members values (null,'1973-10-02');
insert into members values (null,'1977-04-07');
insert into members values (null,'2006-07-03');
insert into members values (null,'2011-10-11');
```